# Remote files to bucket GCP using Snakemake

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snakemake

I'm working on a project using snakemake in GCP VM, i was connected to VM, and when i execute snakemake files,  i get a problem in remoting output files to GCP buckets, here is the error i had

> NoAuthHandlerFound in line 10 of /home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/GCP/snakefile:
> No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/GCP/snakefile", line 10, in 
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/remote/GS.py", line 13, in **init**
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/remote/S3.py", line 35, in **init**
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/remote/S3.py", line 146, in **init**
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/**init**.py", line 141, in connect_s3
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 194, in **init**
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in **init**
> File "/home/fadwa_elkhaddar8/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 1021, in get_auth_handler

Can you please help me how to resolve this problem

I want to have a direct access to GCP bucket to remote and to upload files from there

Comment: Question title: Don't SHOUT at us - people ignore posts like that.

Comment: I don't shout you!! it was my keyboard :)